# Как в форму передать сумму

Tags: javascript, python, html

Раньше я передавал сумму Python переменной.
А сейчас я хочу чтоб пользователь сам вводил сумму. Как это сделать?

```
<script>

                const buy_now_button = document.querySelector('#buy_now_btn')

                buy_now_button.addEventListener('click', event => {
                    let formData = new FormData();
                    formData.append("price", {{ photography.price }});  // ВОТ СЮДА НАДО ПЕРЕДАТЬ СУММУ КОТОРУЮ ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬ САМ ВВЕДЕТ
                    formData.append("title", "{{ photography.title }}");
                    formData.append("photo", "{{ photography.license_file.url }}");
                    formData.append("photochanged", "{{ photography.photo_watermark.url }}");
                    formData.append("url", '{{ photography.get_absolute_url }}');
                    fetch('/checkout/', {
                        method: 'POST',
                        body: formData,
                    })
                        .then((result) => {
                            return result.json();
                        })
                        .then((data) => {
                            let stripe = Stripe(data.stripe_public_key);

                            stripe.redirectToCheckout({
                                {{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}}
                                sessionId: data.session_id
                            }).then(function (result) {
                            });
                        })
                })
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const $form = document.getElementById(`form`);

$form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  fetch($form.action, {
      method: $form.method,
      body: new FormData($form),
    })
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then(data => {
      let stripe = Stripe(data.stripe_public_key);
      return stripe.redirectToCheckout({
        {
          {
            CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID
          }
        }
        sessionId: data.session_id
      })
    })
    .then(result => {})
})
```

```html
<form action="/checkout/" method="POST">
  <input type="number" name="price" value="0">
  <input type="hidden" name="title" value="{{ photography.title }}">
  <input type="hidden" name="photo" value="{{ photography.license_file.url }}">
  <input type="hidden" name="photochanged" value="{{ photography.photo_watermark.url }}">
  <input type="hidden" name="url" value="{{ photography.get_absolute_url }}">
  <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```